# Where to find a unique session ID at design time in .Net WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, sessionid

I've created a custom clipboard because it's not possible to make my whole class map serializable - which is a requirement for the windows clipboard.

However, I need to distinguish between users who are using my clipboard through a unique id. Basically, I want to be able identify a person who is sat at one PC with one or more copies of visual studio (or similar) open.

How do I do that?

ps: This is at design-time.

pps: It's not critical that it should work between copies of visual studio. One copy would be fine, or even one design surface.

Comment: Please explain the scope better. Your clipboard will hold copied objects from where (one pc, one user on one pc, one application instance) and these will be pasted to where, and transported over what?

Comment: The data will be copied in an instance of visual studio on one PC and copied to an instance of visual studio (the same instance or maybe another instance) on the same PC. If the PC has multiple logons then, it should be unique to one logon.

Comment: Actually scrub that about multiple instances of VS. My clipboard just holds a reference to a copy of the class so it obviously needs to be in the same instance of VS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the `USERNAME` and `SESSIONNAME` environmental variables. This should give you a unique ID per logged on session.

You need to combine them in case you have two people logged into the console, whereas the `SESSIONNAME` would be "Console" for both users.

In order to distinguish Visual Studios you could append the process id of VS as well.

If only VS is in question, then the process id should be enough in itself, since two users can't share a process.